# Docker: Can't access binary copied to certain images

Tags: docker

I am trying to access a binary `COPY`ed from the `migrate` container.   When I `COPY` to `python:3.7-alpine` it works, but when I `COPY` to `debian:buster-slim` it can't be found.

Minimum steps to reproduce:

1.Create Dockerfile.test

```
FROM migrate/migrate:v4.6.2 AS migrate
FROM python:3.7-alpine
COPY --from=migrate /migrate /
CMD "/migrate"
```

2. Build and run. This works.

```
docker build . -t migrate_test -f Dockerfile.test
docker run --name migrate_test migrate_test:latest
```

```
Usage: migrate OPTIONS COMMAND [arg...]
       migrate [ -version | -help ]
```

3. Stop and remove container

```
docker stop migrate_test;docker rm migrate_test;
```

4. Change image in Dockerfile.test

```
FROM migrate/migrate:v4.6.2 AS migrate
FROM debian:buster-slim
COPY --from=migrate /migrate /
CMD "/migrate"
```

5. Build and run. This doesn't work

```
docker build . -t migrate_test -f Dockerfile.test
docker run --name migrate_test migrate_test:latest
```

```
/bin/sh: 1: /migrate: not found
```

Comment: What have you tried to do to debug this?  For instance, I might try `docker run --rm --entrypoint /usr/bin/ldd migrate_test /migrate` to see if there are shared library dependencies missing from one vs. the other.  (Removing the `ENTRYPOINT` and setting `CMD ["/migrate"]` would make this less awkward.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Good idea. I just shortened it.  When I exec into the container, `/migrate` is there as a file, but i get the same `not found` error when trying to execute.

Comment: That was it!  Ldd showed a library that was missing on the image. After installing the dependency, it works. The simple `not found` error was throwing me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have things working, but just to clarify the situation for other folks who might find your question:

The issue is that the `migrate/migrate:v4.6.2` is built on the [Alpine](https://alpinelinux.org/) image, which uses [MUSL libc](https://www.musl-libc.org/), whereas most other distributions use [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/). You're getting the "not found" message because the kernel is looking for the dynamic loader whose path is embedded in the image, as we see with the `ldd` command:

```
/ # ldd /migrate
        /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f9e42ebd000)
        libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 => /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f9e42ebd000)
```

This binary will be available on Alpine-based image, but not on images from Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOS, etc. One option is to simply copy over the necessary loader in your Dockerfile:

```
FROM migrate/migrate:v4.6.2 AS migrate
FROM debian:buster-slim
COPY --from=migrate /migrate /
COPY --from=migrate /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1

CMD "/migrate"
```

Another solution would be to rebuild the `migrate` command for your target distribution.