# How to use multi-stage build to eliminate /go/pkg files

Tags: linux, docker, alpine-linux, docker-build

I have this dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.13 as cm_base

ADD ./netrc /root/.netrc

ENV GO111MODULE='on'
ENV GOPROXY='direct'
ENV GOSUMDB='off'

RUN mkdir -p /tmp/cm-go-api
WORKDIR /tmp/cm-go-api

ENV github_token='<some-access-token>'
ADD "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ChannelMeter/cm-go-api/master/go.mod?token=$github_token"  
RUN go mod download 

ENV PROJECT_DIR '/go/src/github.com/channelmeter/cm-go-api'
WORKDIR "$PROJECT_DIR"
RUN git init
RUN git remote add origin 'https://github.com/ChannelMeter/cm-go-api.git'
ARG commit_id
RUN git fetch --depth 1 origin "$commit_id"
RUN git checkout "$commit_id"

RUN go install -v

FROM alpine:3.11.5

COPY --from=cm_base /go/bin /go/bin

EXPOSE 1992 

ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/cm-go-api"]
```

the above breaks tho - the binary executable doesn't seem to work, but if I remove the multi-stage part, it works. For example, I remove these 3 lines:

```
    # FROM alpine:3.11.5
    # COPY --from=cm_base /go/bin /go/bin
```

does anyone know why the binary file produced by the original go build command would not work with alpine?

If I use the original base image, it will work:

```
    FROM golang:1.13
    COPY --from=cm_base /go/bin /go/bin
```

The **error** when using Alpine as the 2nd stage is:

> standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or
>   directory"

Comment: Obviously the binary produced by ubuntu/debian does not work with alpine, but I wonder why

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61491853/docker-cant-access-binary-copied-to-certain-images/61492711#61492711, although this is in fact the converse: you're building something on a glibc based system and attempting to run it on a MUSL-libc based system.

Comment: got it, thanks, if you can link to any more info about the system differences that'd be cool, but that is excellent info, I appreciate it